# Should I use a secondary index or separate ID lookup table in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm migrating a database from mongodb to dynamodb and trying to understand best practices, especially with using secondary local indexes and sort keys.

My application pulls in html data from the web, and loads the data into several tables/collections. At the time of extraction it gives each item an `extracted_id`, unique to the website it's pulled from. Before loading the items, it gives each item a UUID as its primary/partition key.

**Problem:** In order to avoid assigning different uuids to the same `extracted_id` I query the db to check if the entity has a preexisting `entity_uuid`.

**Current Solution:** Currently in mongodb, I have two sets of tables/collections. One for storing all items, and one for storing an entity's `extracted_id`**(as key)** / `entity_uuid` **(as value)** lookup table.

**Better Solution?:** As I move to DynamoDB would it be better to only create one database with `extracted_id` as a local secondary index, as to not store duplicate data? I'm unsure as the docs say to [use indexes sparingly.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForLSI.html) I don't use the `extracted_id` for anything other than providing items with their `uuid` for a given site.

Hopefully this makes sense, I'm new to AWS / DynamoDB and would appreciate any tips / better solutions to the ones mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make `extracted_id` the partition key of your new DynamoDB table and use a ConditionExpression `attribute_not_exists(extracted_id)` to prevent your application from writing duplicate entries?